# How to draw rectangles juxtapose

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawrect

I would like to draw the shape like bellow. After some user event the program have to redraw it with different paramteres: the number and width of boxes were change. It represents busy and free time slots in a period.

[image: sample]

The entire drawing will be in a view control. I know the pseudo-code only:

```
int left = 1;
int upper = 1;
int bottom = 50;
foreach( myDataType item : List<myDataType> ) {
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor( Color.RED );
    Draw( left,  upper, left + item.width, bottom, myPaint );  // red one
    left += item.width;
    myPaint.setColor( Color.GREEN );
    Draw( left,  upper, left + item.nextGap, bottom, myPaint );  // green one
    left += item.nextGap;
}
```

Any ideas wellcome, thanx!

Comment: Create a custom view by extending View, then use your pseudo code in the onDraw() method.

Comment: This question is similar (not similar enough to close this one as duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439456/how-to-create-a-simple-custom-view

Comment: And these articles discuss how to make a custom view: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: @Simon thank you. How can I handle the events? The onDraw() draws one configuration but it will be changed and the program have to redraw the shape. So how can I do it? Is it possible to redraw the object?

Comment: onDraw is called everytime the view draws itself.  To force it to draw, for example after the parameters are changed, just call `view.invalidate();`